# Selecting a target number

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

**Problem Statement**

I am working with a dataset of customers containing past 3 years quarterly data of different branches. The data set looks like this

```
          | Q1-2018 | Q2-2018 | Q3-2018 | Q4-2018
Branch 1  |    20   |   10    |    5    |    25
Branch 2  |    15   |   30    |    3    |    8
Branch 3  |    10   |   12    |    5    |    5
Branch 4  |    0    |    5    |    2    |    1
```

The data has been arranged in a decreasing order according to total no of customers that have made a purchase.

The problem that I am trying to solve is:
How to set a benchmark/target for each branch?

**Attempt**

1. Easiest solve would be to find a minimum or a certain percentile or mean.
2. I have also calculated the upper and lower bounds based on standard deviation and used the lower bound as a possible benchmark

Any thoughts or approach to this?

Comment: What is this "target" intended to achieve?  How would it guide your analysis or management actions?

Comment: The target will act as a benchmark. Think of it as a minimum number that will most likely be achieved every quarter

Comment: That sounds like you are seeking a set of *lower prediction limits.*  It would help to edit your post to clarify this.